Ocasional Android app crash at appModule (maybe Koin)
Ocasional application crashes were observed at "appModule".
After I version-up Koin as below, same crash is not obeseved anymore.
・koin-core  3.2.2 ⇒ 3.4.0
・koin-android   3.3.0 ⇒ 3.4.0
I am assuming the crash was resolveed thanks to Koin fixe but I cannot find information to prove it from release note at Github...
Can anyone help me finding any evidence?
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException:<br/> at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.CachesKt.getOrCreateKotlinClass<br/> at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectionFactoryImpl.getOrCreateKotlinClass<br/> at kotlin.jvm.internal.Reflection.getOrCreateKotlinClass<br/> at com.XXX.XXX-XXX.application.XXXApplication$appModule$1.invoke<br/> at com.XXX.XXX-XXX.application.XXXApplication$appModule$1.invoke<br/> at org.koin.dsl.ModuleDSLKt.module<br/> at org.koin.dsl.ModuleDSLKt.module$default<br/> at com.XXX.XXX-XXX.application.XXXApplication.<init><br/>
I looked up stack-trace and release notes of Koin Github

I would really appreciate If you could help me understanding how to find a root of crash at appModule...
